# Django error page with DEBUG=True much more detailed than logging

Tags: python, django

While `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`, any Python error is shown in a page where I can see not only the traceback but also every local variable at the moment of the exception.

How can I have such a detailed traceback with local variables in my log files, when `DEBUG=False`? I've tried this in `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'django.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

But the only thing that I get in my log file and in the console are the standard Python traceback's, devoid of any detail.

I don't want to know only which line of code caused the error: I also want to know variables values.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if there would be an option to switch the format of the email report to html but i think that's not possible. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write customer logger for this case (see [AdminEmailHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py#L78) for django error log), default django logger doesn't returns you all data.

I would prefer using [sentry](https://sentry.io/for/django/) as bug reporting tool. It is quick to setup and easy to use. It adds lot of meaningful information like local variables, error occurrence, release number, device details, API endpoint and user information.